# He told he had found or found

Tags: past-tense

After he had been watching them for a couple of days he told the police everything he **found out**

Why not **had found** out as he first watched them then found out and then went to the police. 
If you  don't use past perfect, we can think that both actions are happening quite  at the same time which is not true.

May be the meaning is clear enough to avoid past perfect. I don't think so
or may be he found out and immediately went to the police.
Does this kind of phrases work as reported speech "i m going to the police to tell them what I have found"so in reported speech have found becomes had found"

[https://www.liveworksheets.com/worksheets/en/English_as_a_Second_Language_(ESL)/Verb_tenses/Present_(perfect)_-*Past*(perfect)_(2)_bf8998bd](https://www.liveworksheets.com/worksheets/en/English_as_a_Second_Language_(ESL)/Verb_tenses/Present_(perfect)_-_Past_(perfect)_(2)_bf8998bd)

Another sentence seen that I find weird   "I thought he found it last week does it mean i thought that he had found it last week because last week is for the finding not the thinking the thinking came after the finding so past perfect should be better. Am I right here ?

Comment: It could be either. They have slightly different meanings.

Comment: so what is the difference in the meanings if I use past perfect do I emphasize the cause: because he had found out he went to the police and does it mean that all the infos were discovered

Comment: You would use *had found out* for something that happened a while ago, but *found out* for something that just happened. If, after a couple of days, information came to him just before he told the police, it's likely you would not use **had**.

Comment: I don't think that's right at all.   The pluperfect tense in English only indicates that an event happened in the past (to be specific:  the event was completed at some point in the past), it absolutely does not establish a distance in time.  Either use here is fine, because the time period of the second clause defaults to the time clause of the first - exactly as the past tense would necessarily do.   If on the other hand you specified rather than default the second clause's time (`he told the police everything he had found out years ago`), you would definitely need the pluperfect.

Comment: the time period of the second clause defaults to the time clause of the first what do you mean I don't understand "defaults to"